# Azure SearchAsync not getting results

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, async-await, azure-cognitive-search

I have got the Search method to work (it's synchronous, and commented out below); however, the search async method is not working.  It's not returning results... there's no exceptions; it's just stuck waiting.  I've haven't been able to find any examples using Microsoft.Azure.Search version 1.0.0.0 which returns Task> SearchAsync.  I was only able to find 0.9.0.0 which returns a different type (Task> SearchAsync).  Also, I don't have a lot of experience in threading/async programming.  Can someone please help me identify and resolve the issue?  BTW, the ISearchRequest is basically an object that contains the search terms and other things like order by, skip, top, etc., and the GetSearchParameters method just converts that object to a Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.SearchParameters object.  Thanks!

```
    public DocumentSearchResult<T> Search(ISearchRequest request)
    {
        Task.WaitAll(SearchAsync(request));
        var t = SearchAsync(request).Result;
        return t;
        //var searchParameters = _searchHelper.GetSearchParameters(request);
        //SearchIndexClient indexClient = _searchServiceClient.Indexes.GetClient("myIndexName");
        //return indexClient.Documents.Search<T>(request.Terms, searchParameters);
    }

    private async Task<DocumentSearchResult<T>> SearchAsync(ISearchRequest request)
    {
        var searchParameters = _searchHelper.GetSearchParameters(request);
        SearchIndexClient indexClient = _searchServiceClient.Indexes.GetClient("myClientName");
        var documentSearchResult = await indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync<T>(request.Terms, searchParameters);
        //never makes it past above line
        //loop is just here for debug purposes
        foreach(var t in documentSearchResult.Results)
        {
            Debug.Write(t.Score);
        }
        return documentSearchResult;
    }
```

Comment: You probably have a deadlock because you are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code. Try `return Task.Run(() => SearchAsync(request)).Result` as the body of the `Search` method just to verify (don't do this in production code).

Comment: @YacoubMassad, You were correct!  Thanks!  I received results!  How should I do this in production?  Can you either expalin, or send me a link for some guidance.  It'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @YacoubMassad Would you mind summarizing your comments in an official answer to this question? It might help other Azure Search users who are having similar trouble. Thanks!

Comment: @BruceJohnston, I will. But I think I would need more information from OP to provide a useful answer.

Comment: @zBomb, can you explain why you you need to call the async version? Doesn't the API you are using provide a sync version of the `Documents.SearchAsync` method? What is the type of application are you creating?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: Answering in the order you asked...  I wanted to have both sync and async working for a POC; not sure which we will go with.  Yes, like I said the sync version was working (I had it commented out in the code above).  It's just searching a data set with Azure through a Web API at this point.  We are trying to plug it into an existing UI that is slow.  We were hoping azure search would improve performance, which it has.

Comment: @zBomb, there seems to be [a synchronous version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.search.documentsoperationsextensions.search.aspx#M:Microsoft.Azure.Search.DocumentsOperationsExtensions.Search(Microsoft.Azure.Search.IDocumentsOperations,System.String,Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.SearchParameters,Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.SearchRequestOptions)) of the `Search` method from the Azure Search API. Why not use this one for your synchronous `Search` method? If you are worried about duplicate code, you can extract common code into a shared method.

Comment: @YacoubMassad, I am using it... The code I pasted was where I started trying to get async working.  I was using what I had started with with the sync method.  Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear - I was just being lazy until I got the async method working, which I did thanks to you.  I now have two working methods: Search and SearchAsync.  I just wanted to get them both working to be able to show that we can do both sync and async.  Thanks for your help!